# Problem in Ruby Gems Source Installation

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I get the following error while performing the following commmand of adding rubygems.orgs as the gem source.
I am having Windows XP.

```
C:\>gem source --add http://rubygems.org
Error fetching http://rubygems.org:
        SocketError: getaddrinfo: no address associated with hostname. (http://r
ubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Please help me out and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a [DNS issue](http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=48093&forum_id=2), as shown in [this thread](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/156-cant-add-rubygemsorg-source).

```
$ host rubygems.org rubygems.org has address 72.4.120.124
rubygems.org mail is handled by 10 izmunuti.segment7.net.
rubygems.org mail is handled by 20 ziz.jijo.segment7.net.
```

> > I get the same result, i can ping and lookup the URL just fine, I just can't add it to my gem source list :-(
>
> I just accurately tried again, and now I successfully added rubygems as a source. May just have been a network problem.

---

If not, try a [full ruby reinstall as suggested here](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=38553) and check out your [remote sources](http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/camping-list/2010-June/001217.html).

Comment: I was finally able to change the source, but now this problem occurs:

C:\>gem install rails
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  could not find gem rails locally or in a repository

But,I think it will be solved by repeated efforts...
Thanks.

Comment: @Apoorv: rubygems.org is down again? like in http://blog.angelbob.com/posts/285-http-rubygems-org-does-not-appear-to-be-a-repository---published-ruby? http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/rubygems.org doesn't think so but if it was for you, see http://gist.github.com/429688

Answer (score 0):

If anyone gets this on a linux box the solution I found was to use one of Google's nameservers in my `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`